# Banners when Do Not Disturb is on

Tags: iphone, ios, vibrate, do-not-disturb, sound-volume

I just got a new iPhone 5s and I've been trying to adapt it to my needs. 
I do remember that on my 4s, I only switched between silent (with vibrate) and Do Not Disturb modes.
When I was using the phone on **do not disturb**, it did not vibrate but a banner appeared when I received a new SMS or WhatsApp.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce this on my new phone.
Now it seems that I have to choose, when in Do Not Disturb mode, between a completely silent phone (no vibrate and no banners) or a vibrating phone + banners when I receive new messages.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Check your settings for Do Not Disturb. There is an option that allows you to have it enabled while the phone is open, which should disable vibration.

Comment: Yup, but when I do this DND also disables notification banners... So when I receive a message I don't even know I did :(